# TypeCasting : what is difference between below 2 lines of code?

Tags: delphi, delphi-7

what is the difference between below 2 lines of code. Both are trying to get the path and one is working and other is throwing error. i am working on Delphi-7

```
Path:= (((FFormOwner as TForm).Designer) as IDesigner).GetPrivateDirectory; --Working
Path:= IDesigner(TForm(FFormOwner).Designer).GetPrivateDirectory ;  --Error
```

Below is the code which is using line of code to get the path.

```
constructor TsampleComponent.Create(AOwner: TComponent);
begin
  inherited Create(AOwner);
  FFormOwner:=TForm(Owner);
  if not (Owner is TForm) then
    repeat
      FFormOwner:=TForm(FFormOwner.Owner);
    until (FFormOwner is TForm) or (FFormOwner.Owner=nil);

  if (csDesigning in ComponentState) then
    Path:= (((FFormOwner as TForm).Designer) as IDesigner).GetPrivateDirectory
  else
    Path:=ExtractFilePath(Application.EXEName);
.
.

end;
```

Comment: possible duplicate of [What's the difference between casting using (Object as TClass) and TClass(Object)](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2449790/whats-the-difference-between-casting-using-object-as-tclass-and-tclassobject)

Comment: @fantaghirocco It's not a dupe of that because these are interfaces

Answer (score 9, accepted):

```
IDesigner(TForm(FFormOwner).Designer)
```

This performs a simple reinterpretation cast of `Designer`. It will fail because `Designer` is of type `IDesignerHook` which is not the same as `IDesigner`.

```
(FFormOwner as TForm).Designer) as IDesigner
```

This performs a runtime query for `IDesigner` and is resolved with a call to `QueryInterface`. This is the correct way to obtain a different interface from an existing one.